# Apply =IMPORTXML to the whole column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

To scrape a title for a particular page, I am using this formula, which works fine
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//title")

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12BugQYZ8ZfUjHkEH96ezsrrbdtSMpxVPv5oGBFBx2Qc/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to apply this formula to the whole column B, so that when adding urls in column A, column B automatically will be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`importxml` will not work with `arrayformula`. Instead, try this in cell `B1` and drag the formula down:

```
=if(A1<>"",IMPORTXML(A1,"//title"),)
```

Comment: actually, this is how it works right now with simply =IMPORTXML(A1,"//title"), I would like to find the solution with the help of which I will avoid dragging down.